Issues with Automated Generation of Minecraft Item Data Using PrismarineJS
I started a Minecraft project involving automated accounts, and I need the bots to recognize different ways to obtain items. For simplicity, I exclude advanced methods like trading with villagers. I attempted to generate a JSON file listing all Minecraft items and their acquisition methods using JavaScript. However, the generated data contains inaccuracies. For instance, bedrock is marked as mineable and drops bamboo_block, while jungle_log drops yellow_wool.
Here is the relevant part of my JavaScript code and a link to the generated items.json file:

items.json (https://mail.gangnant.fr/cloud/index.php/s/items_json)

const fs = require('fs');
const registry = require('prismarine-registry')('1.20.4');
const {Recipe} = require('prismarine-recipe')('1.20.4');
const Block = require('prismarine-block')('1.20.4');

const items = registry.items;
const blocks = registry.blocks;

function getCraftingRecipes(itemId) {
    const recipesForItem = Recipe.find(itemId, null);
    if (!recipesForItem) return [];
    return recipesForItem.map(recipe => {
        const requiredItems = {};

        if (recipe.inShape) {
            recipe.inShape.forEach(row => {
                row.forEach(ingredient => {
                    if (ingredient) {
                        const itemName = items[ingredient.id] ? items[ingredient.id].name : 'unknown';
                        requiredItems[itemName] = (requiredItems[itemName] || 0) + Math.abs(ingredient.count);
                    }
                });
            });
        } else if (recipe.delta) {
            recipe.delta.forEach(deltaItem => {
                if (deltaItem.id !== itemId) {
                    const itemName = items[deltaItem.id] ? items[deltaItem.id].name : 'unknown';
                    requiredItems[itemName] = (requiredItems[itemName] || 0) + Math.abs(deltaItem.count);
                }
            });
        }

        return {
            required_items: requiredItems,
            obtained_count: recipe.result.count
        };
    }).sort((a, b) => b.obtained_count - a.obtained_count);
}

function getSmeltingRecipe(itemId) {
    // Smelting recipes are not handled by prismarine-recipe, so handle manually
    const smeltingRecipes = [
        {input: 'iron_ore', result: 'iron_ingot'},
        {input: 'deepslate_iron_ore', result: 'iron_ingot'},
        {input: 'gold_ore', result: 'gold_ingot'},
        {input: 'deepslate_gold_ore', result: 'gold_ingot'},
        {input: 'copper_ore', result: 'copper_ingot'},
        {input: 'deepslate_copper_ore', result: 'copper_ingot'},
        {input: 'nether_gold_ore', result: 'gold_ingot'},
        {input: 'ancient_debris', result: 'netherite_scrap'},
        {input: 'sand', result: 'glass'},
        {input: 'red_sand', result: 'glass'},
        {input: 'cobblestone', result: 'stone'},
        {input: 'stone', result: 'smooth_stone'},
        {input: 'netherrack', result: 'nether_brick'},
        {input: 'clay_ball', result: 'brick'},
        {input: 'clay', result: 'terracotta'},
        {input: 'wet_sponge', result: 'sponge'},
        {input: 'cactus', result: 'green_dye'},
        {input: 'kelp', result: 'dried_kelp'},
        {input: 'log', result: 'charcoal'},
        {input: 'wood', result: 'charcoal'},
        {input: 'sandstone', result: 'smooth_sandstone'},
        {input: 'red_sandstone', result: 'smooth_red_sandstone'},
        {input: 'quartz_block', result: 'smooth_quartz'},
        {input: 'andesite', result: 'polished_andesite'},
        {input: 'granite', result: 'polished_granite'},
        {input: 'diorite', result: 'polished_diorite'},
        {input: 'blackstone', result: 'polished_blackstone'},
        {input: 'beef', result: 'cooked_beef'},
        {input: 'chicken', result: 'cooked_chicken'},
        {input: 'porkchop', result: 'cooked_porkchop'},
        {input: 'mutton', result: 'cooked_mutton'},
        {input: 'rabbit', result: 'cooked_rabbit'},
        {input: 'cod', result: 'cooked_cod'},
        {input: 'salmon', result: 'cooked_salmon'},
        {input: 'potato', result: 'baked_potato'},
        {input: 'chorus_fruit', result: 'popped_chorus_fruit'},
        {input: 'sea_pickle', result: 'lime_dye'}
    ];

    const smeltingRecipe = smeltingRecipes.find(recipe => registry.itemsByName[recipe.result].id === itemId);

    if (smeltingRecipe) {
        return {
            input_item: smeltingRecipe.input,
            output_count: 1 // Generally, smelting recipes yield 1 item
        };
    }
    return null;
}

function getMiningInfo(blockName) {
    const block = registry.blocksByName[blockName]
    if (!block) return null;

    let requiredTool = null;
    if (block.harvestTools) {
        const tools = Object.keys(block.harvestTools);
        if (tools.length > 0) {
            requiredTool = items[parseInt(tools[0])]?.name || null;
        }
    }

    let drops = null;
    if (block.drops && block.drops.length > 0) {
        const dropId = block.drops[0];
        drops = registry.items[dropId]?.name || null;
    }

    const mineable = block.diggable || false;

    return {
        mineable: mineable,
        required_tool: requiredTool,
        drops: drops
    };
}

const itemData = {};

for (const itemName in items) {
    const item = items[itemName];
    const itemInfo = {
        craftable: getCraftingRecipes(item.id).length > 0,
        mineable: false,
        obtainable_by_killing: false,
        obtainable_by_smelting: false,
        crafting_recipes: getCraftingRecipes(item.id)
    };

    const smeltingRecipe = getSmeltingRecipe(item.id);
    if (smeltingRecipe) {
        itemInfo.obtainable_by_smelting = true;
        itemInfo.smelting_recipe = smeltingRecipe;
    }

    const block = registry.blocksByName[item.name];
    if (block) {
        const miningInfo = getMiningInfo(item.name);
        if (miningInfo) {
            itemInfo.mineable = miningInfo.mineable;
            itemInfo.required_tool = miningInfo.required_tool;
            itemInfo.drops = miningInfo.drops;
        }
    }

    itemData[item.name] = itemInfo;
}

fs.writeFileSync('items.json', JSON.stringify(itemData, null, 2));

console.log('items.json file has been created.');

Problem: The generated items.json file contains incorrect data, such as bedrock being marked as mineable with bamboo_block drops, and jungle_log dropping yellow_wool. I suspect the issue lies with how IDs are handled, but I can't pinpoint the exact problem.
Expectations: The items.json file should accurately reflect the mineability, correct drops, and crafting recipes of each item.
What I've Tried:

Debugging the code to handle IDs correctly.

Checking the data returned by prismarine-registry and prismarine-recipe.


Could you help me identify and fix the issue in my script?
EDIT:
06/24/2024 10:54

Added let mineable = blockInstance.diggable || false; to check if a block is mineable or not.

Updated the items.json file.


06/24/2024 11:39

Found the issue, the block ID was different from the item ID so it wasn't the same items, fix the program and updated the items.json file.


Bedrock block is listed as mineable because on all items that are blocks when you call getMiningInfo you set mineable: true without checking anywhere if it is actually a mineable block

Thanks, in fact I forgot to check for that, I think I was tired when I did this.

@shindetsu I've modified the script like you told me too, and it in fact worked for some blocks like air, but not for all like bedrock or end_portal_frame for example.

Did you fix your issue already? because i seen in the generated items.json file, now its showing mineable = false for bedrock or end_portal_frame

Yes I forgot to add the fixed script, will do it when I get home sorry !

No problem, glad you solved it and now it works as expected! Cheers
